# How to change the download save directory in ktorrent from a remote host

Tags: ubuntu, ktorrent

So I have ktorrent running on a server and I don't have the ability to see the X11 display for the client, and I need to change my download directory since I like to keep everything very organized. So I need a way to change the download directory for the program as a whole, not like decide where to put each and every torrent that I download. This can't be done through the webui preferences so I'm guessing that I'll have to do it through ssh somehow but from what I've read there really isn't a command to use. Also the way that I have the application run is on startup my server runs the command ktorrent, so it will already be running when I want to change the download location so I assume that I will have to restart the program as well. If anyone knows how to do this it would be much appreciated, and I can't think that I'm the only person to want this feature.

Answer (score 1):

The config is saved in /home/user/.kde/share/conig/ktorrentrc.  Try killing the ktorrent process remotely and editinig the file.  Then restart the app so it will take effect.